# Repeat conditions without reloading the page

Tags: jquery

I have this code here, which seems to work great only after I reload the page.  How can I do this multiple times without reloading the page?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var language_name = $.cookie('language_name');
     if (language_name == "English") {
       $('.selected').click(function() { $('.en').css('display','none');  });                 
     } 

     if (language_name == "Spanish") {
       $('.selected').click(function() { $('.es').css('display','none'); });    
     }
});
```

Comment: How is the cookie set?

Comment: It's actually set later in the code as of right now, but it's working correct as of now since I have set them previously.

Comment: Try putting the code in a function, and calling that function when the language is updated as well as at load...

Comment: Well, I'm not currently re-loading the page in the code, it's only when I reload the page manually that this condition seems to work.  I'm wanting to NOT reload the page, while still using these conditions

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea... Something like `function updateLanguages() { ... }`, and then call it when you want the conditions to run, like right after you set the cookie...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by:

> How can I do this multiple times without reloading the page?

Assuming your code executes before the cookie is set, you will have to reload the page to see it working. If that is the case ...

A switch statement can help setting the default language.

```
// @param ($): jQuery version x?
(function ($) {
    // 1. CONFIGURATION
    var cfg = {
        cookiename: 'language_name',
        selected: '.selected',
        lang: {
            en: '.en',
            es: '.es'
        },
        cssoptions: {
            'display': 'none'
        }
    },

    // 2. OBJECT
    updateLanguages = {
        init: function () {
            var languageName = $.cookie(cfg.cookiename),
                cfgLang = cfg.lang,
                lang;

            switch (languageName.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'spanish':
                    lang = cfgLang.es;
                    break;
                default:
                    lang = cfgLang.en;
                    break;
            }

            this.bindEvent(lang);
            //$.cookie(cfg.cookiename, lang);
        },

        bindEvent: function (lang) {
            $(cfg.selected).click(function () {
                $(lang).css(cfg.cssoptions);
            });
        }
    };

    // 3. DOM READY
    $(function () {
        updateLanguages.init();
    });
} (jQuery));
```

You could add your cookie 'set' function in here as well. Expand `updateLanguages` if needed with functions or configuration options.